# ResourceDictionary not found in design time

Tags: c#, wpf

I have some shared resources that I have bundled within a resource dictionary. The following code works as expected (The resources are loaded at design time and intellisense works perfect.):

***Alternative 1***:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
     <ResourceDictionary>
         <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
             <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MyCompany.Helpers.UI;component/Resources/SharedResources.xaml"></ResourceDictionary>
         </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
     </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

At this point I changed the code to:

***Alternative 2***:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="{x:Static appCode:DesignResource.GlobalResource}"></ResourceDictionary>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

```
public static class DesignResource
{
    public static Uri GlobalResource
    {
        get { return new Uri("pack://application:,,,/MyCompany.Helpers.UI;component/Resources/SharedResources.xaml"); }
    }
}
```

Now Intellisense only gives me: "An error occured while finding the resource dictionary". Am I missing something? Why does *Alternative 2* not work?

Comment: Have you tried to use Properties\DesignTimeResources.xaml and point in there all references?

Comment: First option looks just fine, why do you need a second one?

Comment: @MateusAvelar: I also tried the DesignTimeResources trick, but this also does not give me intellisense support.

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski the first option will load the resources within every usercontrol which will increase loading speed and memory footprint. The second option would give me the chance to just return the uri if design mode is active.